# Cannot View Google Play Console Release Warning Messages

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

When I try to confirm a rollout to internal testers in the Google Play Console for an Android app, I'm getting the following...

> Check these warnings before starting the rollout of this
>   release. Addressing the warnings on this page will ensure your
>   existing users are able to upgrade to the latest version of your app.

If I try to click on the "VIEW WARNING MESSAGES" button below this message, I get

> An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later.

[image]

How can I find out what the warning messages are so I can release my app to testing?

Comment: We're also experiencing this. We had also uploaded an APK with version 1 (without rollout), then replaced the APK with one with version code 2. Not sure if that's relevant, but I noticed you had version code 2 also. We were able to see warnings before, but after mending the 64-bit requirement, we started getting this error.

Comment: Thank goodness. I thought it was just us. This is our first roll-out ever, and I was tearing my hair out.

Comment: I have version 2 because I'd figure I'd try uploading the APK again to see if that helped but it did not.

Comment: @John81 Did it help?

Comment: We're having the same issue when trying to release, only the error-code is different: 2084869337

Comment: @MahNas92 The value is new every time, it is generated

Comment: I figured... couldn't find anything by googling it. But what's the point of having unique, generated error codes if you cannot do anything to identify them? Because, they can surely not only be intended for internal Google analytics purposes?

Comment: The error code is different for every single attempt. Even I experience the same when I try to push to Google beta internal. Did anyone tried upload the apk to Alpha or Beta channels?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: When I posted this I thought maybe this was specific an issue with my APK but now it does appear to be an issue with the Google Play Store.  I agree with the vote to close.

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: Did anyone create a ticket to Google? If yes, please post the ticket number here for future tracking.

Comment: For me, the issue of not being able to see the warnings cleared up this morning.  I can see the warning now but that had nothing to do with the app not being able to be released.  See Vadim Kotov answer below.  Once I filled in all required sections, it let me release the app.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to fill in all required sections in Store Presence in Google Play Console to be able to release the first version. I was confused by this "unexpected error" too.

[image]

Comment: While not being able to view the warnings was an issue on the Google Play Console that seemed to clear up overnight, the real reason the app could not be released was that I had not filled in all required sections in the store listing.  You have to make all the grey checkboxes green, then you can release.  Would be nice to get a message that lets you know that.

Answer (score 1):

This apparently was an internal error within Google Play, that has been cleared up overnight.

Errors have started displaying correctly again.

It's good to know that when a Google error message says, "**Try again later**", unlike most platforms, they *really* mean it. Thanks, Google!

Answer (score 0):

Just tried with app bundle for one of my existing app. Deployed the app to internal beta program. I was successful in publishing.
Guys. May be this is a problem with the apk format.